# How can I prevent iOS keyboard's predictive typing from suggesting a given word?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

I  have an iPhone 12 Mini running on iOS 15. When I click on some text field, e.g. Gmail IOS app's compose box, the iOS keyboard gives me 3 word suggestions, even before I start typing. How can I remove one of these suggestions? I'd like that iOS keyboard never suggests that word, but I still want to use predictive typing.

E.g.,:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Directly change this, I don’t think so.

Your previous actions are the likely source of the word you.

[image]
I’m currently more likely to have another word as my third choice.

[image]

I would recommend resetting the custom dictionary and you will have a blank slate. There’s no path Apple provides to resetting this as [it learns from your typing](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-predictive-text-iphd4ea90231/ios) and [your web site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/104995) use to generate input to the neural engine models that drive  the predictions in supported languages.

[image]

After the reset, you will have a clean start again. I would open a support ticket with Apple if you can’t get it to behave in a useful manner. Perhaps they would allow some inputs if enough people have reproducible issues with it.